Is it correct to use RxJS interval() function for getting real-time updates from the server?
I wrote this code in my Angular app to check for updates in a continuous way.
export class RealTimeComponent {
  products$:any;

  constructor(private service: ProductService){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.products$ = interval(5000)
      .pipe(
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => this.service.getProducts())
      );
  }

}

However, I am worried that calling the server so often could be too expensive and cause performance problems. Do you know if there is a better/more recommended way? Or is it already the right way for doing such a thing? Thank you!

Instead of polling, you could set up a websocket server on your backend and push updates to the frontend as they happen.

Two solutions for you.
You can setup a websocket as suggested in comments
Or you can use JS notification API so server can push silent notification to client (push api is only baseline from march 2023, check here for the compatibility list).
https://angular.dev/ecosystem/service-workers/push-notifications
Client register to notification server and gets URL so that back-end server can send him notification. Then you can push silent notification to client in order to make it reload fresh data
